# (structname/classname) does not name a type C++

Tags: c++

I have an issue with my structs and classes not having a "type"
My code looks like this, I will show for one error:

This my struct "intersection" declared under my "Vector" class in vector.h:

```
struct Intersection {
bool hasIntersection;
Shape *pShape;
float t;
Color color;

Intersection emptyIntersection();};
```

Then this is my include in Shape.cpp where I have a subclass structure with different shapes:

```
#include "../include/Shape.h"
```

This is one of the functions:

```
Intersection Sphere::intersect(const Ray &ray) {
// Sphere naar nul zetten
Ray localray = ray;
localray.origin -= centre;
Intersection localintersection{};

float a = localray.direction.length2();
float b = 2 * localray.direction.dot(localray.origin);
float c = localray.origin.length2() - sqr(radius);

float D = sqr(b) - 4 * a * c;

if (D < 0.0f){
    return localintersection.emptyIntersection();
}

float t1 = (-b - std::sqrt(D)) / (2 * a);
float t2 = (-b + std::sqrt(D)) / (2 * a);

if (t1 > RAY_T_MIN && t1 < RAY_T_MAX) {
    localintersection.hasIntersection = true;
    localintersection.pShape = this;
    localintersection.color = color;
    localintersection.t = t1;
}
else if(t2 > RAY_T_MIN && t2 < RAY_T_MAX) {
    localintersection.t = t2;
}
else{
    return localintersection.emptyIntersection();
}}
```

And this is the top part of my Shape class in Shape.h

```
virtual Intersection intersect(const Ray& ray) = 0;
```

It is giving me the errors that 'Shape' does not name a type for my struct, and Intersection does not name a type for my Shape.h class. I do not know how to solve it, I have seen many other topics which have solutions, but none of these work

EDIT:

declaration of Shape and a subclass

```
class Shape {
public:

    virtual Intersection intersect(const Ray& ray) = 0;
};

class Shapeset : public Shape{
protected:
    std::vector<Shape*> shapes;

public:
    Shapeset();

    void addShape (Shape* shape);

    virtual Intersection intersect(const Ray& ray);
};
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. There is no declaration for `Shape` in the code you posted.

Comment: I added my declaration

Comment: This is far from a minimal reproducible example so I have to guess.. Maybe you have a circular include path where 2 or more headers include each other.

Comment: In your `Intersection` header file, don't include the `Shape` header, instead just do `class Shape;`

Comment: drescherjm and @ChrisMM you both saved my day, struggled on this for like 4 hours, thanks a lot

Comment: Off-topic: `Intersection emptyIntersection()` does not look like a good idea. I'd assume it should either get a *static* member function (why should you need an instance just for creating anthother empty one?) or far better a constructor producing an empty intersection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your header with Intersection declaration doesn't have Shape declaration.

Use code:

```
class Shape;

struct Intersection { ...
```

There is same trouble with Shape header: header doesn't have Intersection declaration.
I recommend you to include intersection header into shape header.